# how can i add background-image under css3 gradient effect have low opacity

Tags: html, css

my photoshop design have gradient colors,have 64 opacity and it have pattern i' m have already succeeded in do gradient and low it opacity like my code example in topic but my Question is how i can add to it the pattern

```
display: block;
position: relative;
width:100%;
height:100%;
background: rgba(137,206,157,1);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(137,206,157,1) 0%, rgba(74,187,154,0.64) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(137,206,157,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(74,187,154,0.64)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(137,206,157,1) 0%, rgba(74,187,154,0.64) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(137,206,157,1) 0%, rgba(74,187,154,0.64) 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(137,206,157,1) 0%, rgba(74,187,154,0.64) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(137,206,157,1) 0%, rgba(74,187,154,0.64) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#89ce9d', endColorstr='#4abb9a', GradientType=0 );
```

Comment: What do you mean by "add under"? Can you please be more specific?

Comment: Try putting a complete example or a link to JS fiddle. I'm not clear either on what under you are referring to.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you may be able to do `background-image: (gradient code), (image code);`. If not you could always put the gradient on a pseudo element and position it over the parent

Comment: my photoshop design have gradient colors,have 64 opacity and it have pattern i' m  have already succeeded in do gradient and low it opacity like my code example in topic but my Question is how i can add to it the pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
1) #your box {
background-image: url('XX.gif');
/* here your code /*
}

2) 
<div id="box">
<div id="your_box">
</div>
</div>


#box {
background-image: url('XX.gif'); /* or put here a css3 grandient effect instead
background-color: #XY;
display: block;
position: relative;
width:100%;
height:100%;
overflow:hidden;
}

#box #your_box {
here your code
}
```

Comment: i'm graphic designer http://themeforest.net/user/LionCodes it my portfolio i hope if u can add me here to ask u about thing in html,css codes fb.com/gohawise